# I really need help with frozen Facebook settings

Tags: facebook

[image]

I am at my wit's end with a problem on Facebook and I don't know who to ask.

I've had this problem for almost a year but now its really an issue.

When I try and change my 'seen as active' settings on the FB desktop chat sidebar, I click on the gear icon and I get the little pop up with the options but when I make a new choice it won't work. No matter what new combination I try, when I click "okay" nothing happens and the box just sits there but when I click cancel, it will close again.  when i try and delete my previous settings ("friendslist2)-i can in the box-- but then after i press okay and nothing happens i see "friendslist2" returned to the window.

### Troubleshooting

- I've tried on 3 different browsers(Chrome, Safari, and Opera).  i also tried in incognito mode and even on a different laptop altogether.
- I've cleared my cache, cookies, content settings, and autofill content.
- I went on mbasic and also the Messenger app to see if I could toggle the options there but that specific set of options do not exist in either place.

I have a Macbook Pro running Mojave.

I am stuck with a really unfortunate set up as far as who can/can't see me active. I really need to change my settings for the sidebar and would be really grateful for some help!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if this seems like a basic response, but you might have people left in your "turn off chat except for" dialogue box, which can cause issues. Delete all the names from any of those menus (turn off chat for all except, turn off chat for x only) etc

https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10152195578378268

Comment: thank you!!!  no its not basic i thought of it too!!!! it makes a lot of sense.  i thought maybe someone is sitting there that deactivated or something?  so i put in 00000000000 til it was full of 0's and deleted them?  i didnt know what else to try.

Comment: they come up as tags iirc (like blue boxes with the name) if theres anyone there, this should include deactivated accounts. i would legitimately add someone to it, save, then go back and try to remove them and save again. it might force facebook into working.

Comment: if only!!!   i cant save anything i add.  it wont register it.

something is preventing it from recognizing anything i put in the boxes or any selection i make except 'cancel'

Comment: Last thing I can think of would maybe be using your phone in desktop mode, in case its an issue with your computer and not just your browsers (since you changed browsers and tried the mobile app already)

https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/safari-101-request-desktop-sites-your-iphone-0163057/

Comment: oh thank you i will try that.  i appreciate your time!

Comment: it would not open those options on the phone so i jumped on an old laptop that i have (barely works but can surprise me)  and it did work tonight so i can say sadly that was the end of the luck.  exact same issue on that device too.

Comment: Maybe you could message a fb admin and ask if theres any restrictions on your account? This is really odd...

Comment: i have sent about 5 pleading reports to the support inbox for broken issues and they just write back 'thanks for your feedback'

Comment: this might go against the rules of the forum, but you could try and draw a fb admins attention by making a big fuss on their support forum (the public one that people can discuss on) or twitter if you have enough friends/connections to blow it up. sometimes bad reputation gets a response from 'em.

Comment: ITS STILL GOING ON,  ARRRGGGGG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: i am still having this issue and just as frustrated.  i wish someone could help me with it.